# hosting xbap on asp

Tags: asp.net, xbap

I have problem with hosting xbap on ASP.NET
I have two project XBAP and ASP.NET

I set xbap source in ASP.NET like this

```
 <iframe src="\PNAB\ASP-XBAP\Publish2\Application Files\pnabXBAP_1_0_0_\pnabXBAP.xbap" width="500" height="300" />
```

and open ASP.net in IE
and I see only frame without XBAP file
what can be problem with this?
when I open directly XABAP it is run.

Answer (score 1):

Open fiddler and see if the request is returning a 404 error. You may just have the wrong reference in there (also use forward slashes unless you mean to use the local file system in that case you have security zone issues) I would put in the full url http://whatever/pnab/asp-xbap/etc

Comment: my all path to file is  

<iframe src="C:\Users\Desktop\PNAB\ASP-XBAP\Publish2\Application Files\pnabXBAP_1_0_0_\pnabXBAP.xbap" width="500" height="300" />

maybe here is problem?

Comment: if your webpage is not running from the local file system (c:\whatever.html) then this is definitely an issue. You can't by default reference local files through your browser to run as this is a security issue. You can _try_ adding that url to your trusted sites list in internet explorer.